# How to build a custom icon using existing material ui icons?

Tags: css, svg, material-ui

I want to create an arrow as shown in the below image

[image]

I got it using svg -

```html
<svg height='24' width='12' style={{ marginBottom: '-4px', marginLeft: '49%' }}>
  <line x1='6' y1='0' x2='6' y2='28' style={{ stroke: '#D0D0D7', strokeWidth: 2 }} />
  <polyline points='0,14 6,8 12,14' style={{ fill: 'none', stroke: '#D0D0D7', strokeWidth: 2 }} />
</svg>
```

But I want to use material ui icon and there is no material ui icon where the upward arrow head is at the middle of the line.

The following are available in material ui

1. [image: arrow without line] - arrow without a line
2. [image: arrow at top of the line] - arrow head at top of the line

Is there a way of using the `KeyboardArrowUp` icon from option 1 and put it at the middle of a line? or any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#svg-icons)?

Comment: Try this: `<svg viewBox="0 0 12 24" style="margin-bottom: -4px; marginLeft: 49%;">
  <line x1='6' y1='0' x2='6' y2='24' style="stroke: #D0D0D7; strokeWidth: 2; fill: none;" />
  <polyline points='0,14 6,8 12,14' style="fill: none; stroke: #D0D0D7; strokeWidth: 2" />
</svg>` Add a width for the svg element

Comment: @Sfili_81 There is no material ui icon with arrow head at the middle of the line. I updated the question to mention this. Is there a way of building custom icon I need from existing icons?

Answer (score 0):

i guess it clear in the doc .. https://material-ui.com/components/icons/
but either way you can use SvgIcon or the normal icon

`function HomeIcon(props) => (<SvgIcon {...props}><path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z"/></SvgIcon>);`
or use

`<Icon color="primary">add_circle</Icon>`

Comment: There is no material ui icon with arrow head at the middle of the line. I updated the question to mention this. Is there a way of building custom icon I need from existing icons?

Comment: you can create a SVG in Photoshop and export it into the web , and even animate it... or wrap the icons in a container / div  and animate them if that what you want